# I got this error while trying to run unity game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

> **'UnityEngine.Application'** does not contain a definition for `isBatchMode`

I'd look through the code, it didn't show any errors when I compiled but when I go back to unity the error still exists.
[image]

this is the code
[image]

I use unity 2017.4.37f1.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Please show us some code!

Comment: In details of error there is also file in which error occurred and besides file there is something like `(14, 28)`` which indicates that error is in 14th line. Look at that line.

Comment: Which unity version are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to replace `Application.isBatchMode` with

```
UnityEditorInternal.InternalEditorUtility.inBatchMode
```